# How to get lib files list under specific path in bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

Here is my bat file:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set DebugLibNames=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"dir /s/b *.lib ..\3rdlib\Debug\ 2>nul"') do (
    set DebugLibNames=%%DebugLibNames%%, %%a
)

echo DebugLibNames:%DebugLibNames%

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
lib.exe /OUT:world.lib %DebugLibNames%

pause
```

What I want is get a list of lib file names, then pack them to a big lib with lib.exe.

However, the DebugLibNames is empty, how do I fix it?

Comment: Replace line `set DebugLibNames=%%DebugLibNames%%, %%a` with `set DebugLibNames=!DebugLibNames!, %%a`…

Comment: Also be aware that commandline lengths have a limitation, so you'll need to be careful with the depth of your directory tree and the number of lib files within it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested, but seems likely to work or be close. :-)

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File 'Do-It.ps1'
```

=== Do-It.ps1

```
$DebugLibNames = Get-ChidItem -Path @('.', '..\3rdlib\Debug') -Filter '*.lib' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Host "DebugLibNames:$($DebugLibNames -join ', ')"
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
& lib.exe /OUT:world.lib $($DebugLibNames -join ', ')"

pause
```